# private iRedMial server, [127.0.0.1] in email headers

Tags: email

I have installed a private email server using iRedMail on CentOS6. When I used it to send email to my outlook account, I found '127.0.0.1' in the header, the header show below:

```
<blink>

I have installed a private email server using iRedMail on CentOS6. When I used it to send email to my outlook account, I found '127.0.0.1' in the header, the header show below:

<code>
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRyU+pBy2R9QCCqBNiBLR/yls0BoNbTHNzodM77HDB36iyk5ZBzqcXCVkFUHscSOlWuYdBLP6fzGxAYcwEDRkN6dTR+oUakT6ZdlWGlcaxL2z1N3tMpU1rVw=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=softfail (sender IP is 89.***.***.171; identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed) smtp.mailfrom=myname@outlook.com; dkim=none (identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed) header.d=outlook.com; x-hmca=fail header.id=myname@outlook.com
X-SID-PRA: myname@outlook.com
X-AUTH-Result: FAIL
X-SID-Result: FAIL
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Message-Info: M98loaK0Lo2XMbcPamiQkpO+xJvB2uwbihYH5SYjkZZFRNQTaSCvCUd/itHi/2Z/Dxduhk5lYUNSiDE4GU+PUNbDmxDdLTU3nhQn/J1qti+xpM8d/JBaxDpn8UyWgS/4vcQYd1JbxFh7TawrHhaQ9rkJZJLRRetAff4zhjWfsuawkdewoWwJRZbVVvgzKUypOi8M2ihwn5y+mvzUwn2ld9H/1W7NncBK2+Q59+YmV7KbzWmu//gRBA==
Received: from mail.mydomain.com ([89.***.***.171]) by COL004-MC5F27.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Thu, 20 Aug 2015 02:20:18 -0700
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (mail.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 625EB1C06B7
    for <myname@outlook.com>; Thu, 20 Aug 2015 11:20:30 +0200 (CEST)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mail.mydomain.com
Received: from mail.mydomain.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.com (mail.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id m7eG6oP8jkcB for <myname@outlook.com>;
    Thu, 20 Aug 2015 11:20:29 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from _ (mail.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 8E3B81C06A8
    for <myname@outlook.com>; Thu, 20 Aug 2015 11:20:29 +0200 (CEST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2015 17:20:28 +0800
From: myname <myname@outlook.com>
To: myname@outlook.com
Subject: Server Error
Message-ID: <41572de3bac2c828b9d245beeca7ba67@mydomain.com>
X-Sender: myname@outlook.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail
Return-Path: myname@outlook.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 20 Aug 2015 09:20:18.0415 (UTC) FILETIME=[6E48C7F0:01D0DB29]
</code>

Hello,
   My email server has an error.
</blink>
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

### webmail - 127.0.0.1:25

Your `roundcube` webmail submits messages via smtp connection to `127.0.0.1:25`. Your webmail may directly execute `sendmail` command (provided by postfix) to avoid `127.0.0.1` in this header.

```
Received: from _ (mail.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 8E3B81C06A8
    for <myname@outlook.com>; Thu, 20 Aug 2015 11:20:29 +0200 (CEST)
...
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail
```

### anti-spam "sandwich"

Your SMTP/MTA/postfix server passes messages via SMTP to amavis (anti-spam)  and receives it back via smtp.  You may use milter (amavisd milter or MIMEDefang milter) to integrate spamassassin with postfix/sendmail another way.

```
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (mail.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 625EB1C06B7
    for <myname@outlook.com>; Thu, 20 Aug 2015 11:20:30 +0200 (CEST)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mail.mydomain.com
Received: from mail.mydomain.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.com (mail.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id m7eG6oP8jkcB for <myname@outlook.com>;
    Thu, 20 Aug 2015 11:20:29 +0200 (CEST)
```